# Structuring externally scraped content

Tags: structure, entries-field, content, count

I scrape content from an external website using JSON API with the FeedMe plugin. Content is saved as entries with plain text and redactor-type Fields.

How can I structure this content so that I can display the most used words?

Example: I fetch content from a chess website. I want to find words or chess terminology (i.e. bishop, checkmate, pawn etc.) that are most often used, and list it like this:

1. bishop (302)
2. pawn (278)
3. checkmate (201)
4. stalemate (154)

...and so forth.

The number in parenthesis would be the number of times that word or term is counted in the scraped content.

Have anyone done anything similar? I would guess there are many use-cases for this, but couldn't find any relevant discussions on it.

Comment: Do you have a predefined list of those _words_?

Comment: I do not have a predefined list of words. But an acceptable solution would be to define such a list if neccessary.